# filter activity in azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to make a pipeline which filters the input from the source but can not find a way to store the output from the filter in some table or any file.

this is the error if I try to save the output from the filter activity:
[image]

this is the expression as an input for copy activity
[image]

This is the same problem I face even when I try to store the output from metadata activity in a table or any file

Answer (score 0):

Please check the output of copy filter activity in the output tab, I think `@activity('MyFilterActivity').output.value` would be an array.

The query does not support an array as input. You can use `@activity('MyFilterActivity').output.value[0]` or `foreach` activity.

Comment: I have already used foreach activity in the pipeline and also tried the expression you suggested but its not working . I want to store the output in a table.

Comment: Can you find a way to transfer the array to a sql statement in the query?

Comment: have you considered trying something like a "@activity('MyFilterActivity').output.value.join(',')" for a delimited string of some sort?